# How to join optional child table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select data from following table. (AWS RDB, Serverless Aurora MySQL)

Table.1 user

```
| id | name    |
|----|---------|
|  1 | Alpha   |
|  2 | Bravo   |
|  3 | Charlie |

* id is PK.
```

Table.2 avatar

```
| id | user_id | image_path |
|----|---------|------------|
|  1 |       1 | 1.jpg      |
|  2 |       2 | 2.jpg      |
|  3 |       1 | 1-2.jpg    |

* id is PK.
* user_id is FK user.id
```

- user can upload avatar image optionally.
- user can not delete avatar. append only.

Expect

- If exists avatar, it will selected of max of id.
- If not exists avatar, selected as NULL.

```
| user_id | user_name | avatar_id | avatar_image_path |
|---------|-----------|-----------|-------------------|
|       1 | Alpha     |         3 | 1-2.jpg           |
|       2 | Bravo     |         2 | 2.jpg             |
|       3 | Charlie   | NULL      | NULL              |
```

Now, I wrote this SQL.

```
SELECT
  user.id AS user_id,
  user.name AS user_name,
  avatar.id AS avatar_id,
  avatar.image_path AS avatar_image_path
FROM user
LEFT JOIN avatar ON avatar.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
HAVING MAX(avatar.id);
```

but, row of `user_id = 3` was not selected.

Output

```
| user_id | user_name | avatar_id | avatar_image_path |
|---------|-----------|-----------|-------------------|
|       1 | Alpha     |         3 | 1-2.jpg           |
|       2 | Bravo     |         2 | 2.jpg             |
```

How should I do?

Comment: Something like `HAVING MAX(avatar.id) OR avatar.id IS NULL;` ?

Comment: thanks advice Strawberry. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a93d8de/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this below script-

```
SELECT A.*,C.image_path
FROM user A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  user_id,max(id) id
    FROM  avatar
    GROUP BY user_id
) B ON A.id = B.user_id
LEFT JOIN avatar C ON B.id = C.id
```

Comment: The solution without HAVING clause and OR operator!

Comment: @KoheiSugimura nice to see the logic helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  user.id AS user_id,
  user.name AS user_name,
  avatar.id AS avatar_id,
  avatar.image_path AS avatar_image_path
FROM user
LEFT JOIN avatar ON avatar.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
HAVING MAX(avatar.id) OR avatar.id IS NULL;
```